# Thousands separator (comma) in term id

Tags: 7, views

I'm rewriting the results in a view. I've added taxonomy term ID field and hidden it from displaying.

This is the rewriting code:

```
<a href="/publications/working-area/[tid]">[name]</a>
```

This is the result generated:

```
<a href="/publications/working-area/1,007">Constitution</a>
```

The problem is the comma in [tid]. I want Drupal to not to insert comma there i.e.. instead of 1,007 I want 1007.

Comment: I think, you can do that in view field settings.

Comment: Yeah, isn't there a "number format" select list on the settings for that field?

Answer (score 4):

Go to your view. and Click on Taxonomy term to configure the field. Make sure to select the **Thousand marker** as `<none>`.

[image]

Then you can use this as replacement pattern in your href path