# Get views contextual filter's argument value in thousand

Tags: civicrm, views

I have a Civicrm set up in Drupal 7. I am showing Civicrm data using two different views.

In one of the view I have set contextual filter to get the contact IDs. From another view I am passing contact IDs as the contextual argument.

Now the issue is, the filter is not working for those IDs which are in thousand. For e.g. 1,223.

Further, when i used the Views php module to pass php value to remove that comma, it is creating Ajax internal server error.

Below is the code, I used in views php field.

```
<?php echo str_replace(',', '', $row->contact_id); ?>
```

I have checked below link, but that is also not working in this case

[Thousands separator (comma) in term id](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/121813/thousands-separator-comma-in-term-id)

Please suggest a solution which will work without any ajax issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data_query_alter().
 *
 * @param $view
 *   Information about Views' tables and fields.
 *
 * @param $query
 *   Information about query used in this views.
 */
function my_module_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  // Only edit your view whose contextual filter need to be edited.
  if ($view->name == 'your_view_name'){

    // Get your contextual filter field and use your code to strip comma.
    // str_replace(',', '', $row->contact_id);
  }
}
```